# Convert unknown symbols to cyrillic

Tags: unicode, symbols, cyrillic

I have this kind of symbols in db table (РќР°РёРјРµ) , and I don't know who inserted this data to table.Is there any way to convert them to cyrillic ?

Comment: you have to know which encoding is used to encode the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,  you can do the conversion.  Since you haven't mentioned any langauge, so the logic is given:

1. Assuming the string length is even, take two immediate characters.
2. Combine the underlying byte values of two characters to give a 16 bit value. This gives you the multi-byte value of Cryllic character. You can decode the value to give its representation using a proper decoding format like `utf-8`.
3. Repeat points 1 and 2 for next two characters until the end of string.

If you want, you can implement it in any language of your choice.

Comment: Thank you for answer! Can it be done in oracle sql ?

Comment: Yes you can do it in PL/SQL of Oracle. Do you know what it is?

Comment: Moreover, it can be done in Oracle SQL itself, but it needs figuring out how to do it. Look out for encoding functions to do it in SQL statement itself.

Comment: Please be kind to tell, how to take or what command to use to take byte value of symbol(or char) ?

Comment: You are implementing in what platform? Oracle SQL? You have either two ways: direct or indirect. Direct way is to do in SQL a statement and indirect way is to use a scripting language like PHP, Python, RoR, or .net through which you can update the converted value in database. Latter is easier than the former. Do you understand it?

Comment: Ask any doubts you have. What will you do with the converted values? Will you update the database? Or will you keep the database as it is and present the converted values to the users?

Comment: Please tell how you solved your problem. What technique did you follow?

Comment: Actually my main problem was not decoding symbols,but it was one way to solve it.So I found different solution,because dealing with decoding will take a lot of time

Comment: Could you please mention in brief what the solution was.